# Symmetry of interaction lagrangian and symmetry of full lagrangian

Tags: symmetry, renormalization, perturbation-theory, beyond-the-standard-model, effective-field-theory

Suppose we have lagrangian
$$
\tag 1 L = \frac{\theta}{f_{\gamma}}F_{EM}\tilde{F}_{EM} +\frac{1}{2}(\partial_{\mu}\theta)^2 - \frac{1}{2}m_{\theta}^2\theta^2 + L_{SM},
$$
where $\tilde{F}_{EM}$ denotes dual EM strength tensor, $\theta$ is pseudoscalar field, $L_{SM}$ denotes Standard model lagrangian.

Since theory given by $(1)$ is nonrenornalizable, infinite number of effective interactions will be produced through loops. My question is about symmetries which exist for these interactions.

Let's look to $(1)$. The mass term for $\theta$ fields breaks explicitly shift symmetry $\theta \to \theta + c$, but the interaction term preserves it, since
$$
\theta F_{EM} \tilde{F}_{EM} \equiv \theta \partial_{\mu}K^{\mu} \to -\partial_{\mu}\theta K^{\mu}
$$
The question: does shift symmetry of interaction term of tree-level lagrangian $(1)$ tell us that induced effective interactions will preserve shift symmetry?

Or the explicit symmetry breaking of mass term will produce nonsymmetric interaction terms?

An edit. Such term will produce symmetry breaking (nonlocal) interactions only if they are mediated through $\theta$ propagator.

Comment: Sorry I am not an expert in this but I'd really like to learn. To make $\theta$ interact with the EM field, shouldn't you include a $J^{\mu}_{\theta}A_{\mu}$ term? Where $J^{\mu}_{\theta}$ is the 4-current of your field. What is the physical meaning of a term $\propto \theta F^2$?

Comment: @SuperCiocia : $\theta$ field is like pion $\pi^{0}$ in QCD; it is pseudoscalar, it has no EM charge, but interacts with EM field through anomalous term $F_{EM}\tilde{F}_{EM}$. In principle, in fundamental theory $\theta$ may arise as Goldstone boson, as pion arises during QCD crossover. And then such small explicit symmetry breaking term generates its mass, as well as quark mass term generates mass for pseudoscalar mesons.